# rabbitmq: how to setup routing keys per queue (and message) so that it can get messages for that queue and message destined for all queues in a topic?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am very new to messaging and rabbitmq and trying to setup bindings in rabbitmq control panel to support the following scenario (pardon the pseudo):

1. queue named `one`
2. queue named `two`

I would like to send message destined:

1. only for `one`
2. only for `two`
3. for both `one` and `two`

Currently rabbitmq setup looks like this:

`to: one; routing: one;`
`to: two; routing: two`

When I publish a message I use this kind of setup:

`routing key: one` -> message is delivered to `one`;

`routing key: two` -> message is delivered to `two`;

With what routing key value do I publish a message so that both queues receive it? Or how do I setup my bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up wild card characters for your routing keys.

You could do `routing_key: 'all'`, `routing_key: 'all.one'`or `routing_key: 'all.two'`

Obviously the example is contrived and you would choose more meaningful routing key names like `"logging.telegraf"` or `"logging.events"`or "weather.houston" etc. Basically you can set up something of a hierarchy using dotted notation.

Hope that helps.

Check out the official docs on topics and the use of `*` or `#`
http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-ruby.html

Comment: This doesn't work for me: ```all.*``` isn't delivered to both queues. Message is delivered to ```all.one``` when routing key is set to ```all.one``` and to ```all.two``` when routing key is set to ```all.two```.

Comment: You can create multiple bindings with the pattern you expect. So for each queue you would have to create binding for `all` and binding for `all.one`/`all.two`

Comment: this works. Using all.* doesn't work, so perhaps you can edit your answer so I can accept it?